# How can I transport a file from my Windows ME using VirtualBox to the host?

Tags: virtualbox, email, microsoft-outlook, file-transfer, windows-98

I need to pick up a file located inside a Windows ME running from VirtualBox and put it in whatever else (e.g. the host system), but I'm being unable to do it thanks to a series of problems:

- The basic copy and paste files between host and virtual machine is not working, despite being enabled
- I'm being unable to access a server which I could use as temporary holder; it simply doesn't accept connection even though I have edited Samba to make it work as told [here](http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/win9x_samba.htm).
- I can't access any e-mail: for some reason, each time I try to access GMail, Outlook, Yahoo! and even Brazilian's BOL it simply never works (tried with the installed IE and two other browsers compatible with Windows ME), stopping when it comes to the page where the connection should be established. This is the most relevant part, since sending by Gmail was the traditional way of doing this till some time ago. In fact, most websites has some problem or other when are loaded, but they all fail when comes the access e-mail account part.
- The native Microsoft Outlook is unable to send messages for some reason - I guess it's because I don't know how to properly configure it so it. I tried to use Hotmail's default url (.asp something), but I only got errors.
- No USB connection available
- Unable to install any FTP solution such as FileZilla (outdated system)
- Dropbox and OneDrive pages don't even load; Google Drive can't be accessed because browser is incompatible.

Does anybody has any other suggestion? Or is aware of a particular useful solution to any of the failed attempts listed above?

Comment: There's several of ME-compatible FTP clients out there to download (heck it may even include `ftp.exe` already), why not use one of those?  Also, why not upload the file to an online service like DropBox, OneDirve, Google Drive, etc. via their web sites?

Comment: Perhaps using an old version of Firefox might get you around the web better:  ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/2.0.0.20/win32/en-US/

Comment: Are you able to right-click on a folder and select sharing? Share that folder. If the WinME box is on the same network as your host, then the should be able to see it. It just sounds like a network configuration issue as you should be able to put the ME on the same network or NAT it underneath the host.

Comment: I've also had trouble with copying files from host to guest OS and vice-versa. On your guest it sounds like a network problem.

Comment: You DO have guest additions installed dont you? It also sounds as though you have configured host networking correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a program such as WinMount (paid unfortunately, but has a free trial), which will allow you to mount the hard drive disk image as a drive on your host machine, at which point you can interact with it unfettered.

Comment: Do it for free in Linux: https://askubuntu.com/questions/19430/mount-a-virtualbox-drive-image-vdi